# Why so high Peak Memory Use & Total Request Time in a cakephp app?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

My timer log is as follow:
[image]

My `27` datebase queries took `21 ms

One of the queries affected `2919` rows.
My view displays those 2919 rows.

Why does it take so long to load the page?
Is it because rendering all that Html?

**Is there any way to minimise the Peak Memory Use  & the Total Request Time ?**

EDIT:
In my controller:

```
$this->XXX->bindModel(
                array('hasAndBelongsToMany' =>
                    array(
                        ...
                        )
                    )
                )
        );
```

use `find('all')` (a lot of data about 2919 rows)
and `set` the results
That's all

Comment: you are processing and displaying 2919 rows in a page and you ask why it's so slow? geez.. We need to know more about what you're doing to give you advice how to trim it down.

Comment: Maybe if you didn't display 2919 rows at the same time? Can you use paging?

Comment: @Juhana I want to display all those rows at once - so you suggest rendering html overloads the server so much? If so why controller action took 2075 ms?

Comment: Because whatever your controller is doing (which we don't know) is taking so long. Doesn't seem unreasonable for nearly 3000 records, with the way Cake is handling it by default.

Comment: @Anh Pham I'm generating a big site map - I want it displayed in one Html page - I'd like to know what exactly uses so much memory

Answer (score 2):

When you pull the data from the database make sure you limit the results only to fields that you need by using `fields` or [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable). Managing and creating large arrays from database query results takes a lot of time.

Also, if you're creating a site map you could cache the results since usually the contents don't change that often (depends on the project of course).

Comment: Thx, it reduced server usage almost twice.